# how avoid 0 to be entered in first position text box using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

i know its possible duplicate. but existing solution is not working out for me.

field should accept like below.

**valid** - **123,33.00**,
          **100,897,99,**
          **8000**
          **10334**
          **9800,564,88.36**

**invalid - 001, 0, 01234234, -123, 1.44, .99, 12asdf, 12ASDF, asdf123, ASDF34**

codes so far. below code is in ngOninit()

```
 $("#amoutField").on("keypress keyup", function() {
    if ($(this.amtField).val() == '0') {
        $(this.amtField).val('');
    }
});
```

another method am having is to restrict range

```
avoidZero(e, field) {
  if (field.name === "amoutField ") {
        e = (parseInt(e) == 0) ? 0 : e;
        this.amoutField = e.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        $("#amoutField").val(this.amoutField);
    }
 }

<input class="wdh100p" type="text" id="amoutField" name="amoutField " value="" maxlength="5" 
[ngModel]="amoutField "  (ngModelChange)="avoidZero($event, amts)">
```

Comment: `console.log(/^[^0]/.test('0test');`

Comment: Please, please, please don't change the value of a text input on key press. It's a horrible, terrible user experience. Just show an error message beneath it or something.

Comment: agree with @JDB. Better change the value on blur event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression and simply remove all the leading zeros when the input value changes...

```js
$("#amountField").on("input", function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/^[0]*/, "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="amountField" />
```

Note: Using the `input` event covers all possible ways the value of the input can change (copy/paste, drag/drop etc.)

Comment: it should user to enter 0 but it should removed when he release the key. in your snippet its not allowing to enter at the beginning

Comment: It does actually get entered, but it's removed immediately.  Is there a reason you want the user to see the number appear and then disappear?

Comment: @Idiot_cheg I don't know what's the reason of show `0` and then remove off.  I consider this answer the best approach. :-)

Comment: i dont see 0 to be entered

Comment: @Idiot_cheg I understand.

Comment: but the requirement am having is like that bro .. :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the events to handle different situations:

### Situations

- User typing zero at first position
- User dragging value from another field to this field.
- User typing number and then typing zero at first position.

```js
$("#amoutField").on("keydown", function(e) {
  if ($(this).val().trim().length === 0 && e.keyCode === 48) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}).on("keyup", function() {
  handleKeyupFocus(this);
}).on('focus', function() {
  handleKeyupFocus(this);
}).on('drop', function() {
  var $self = this;
  setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
    handleKeyupFocus($self);
  }), 0);
});

var handleKeyupFocus = function(target) {
  while ($(target).val().startsWith("0")) {
    $(target).val($(target).val().substring(1));
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Try to drag, paste zeros from another field, clipboard, Etc.</p>
<input id="amoutField">
```

Comment: tnx, thats almost great. but have show user that the field should not start with 0. when he tries to enter 0 its should disappear at the moment he entered.  here i dont want to use copy paste. how to stop **dragging** in your code

Comment: @Idiot_cheg sorry, but I didn't understand.  Can you explain what's wrong in this answer? :-)

Comment: no.. almost right thats wat i looking for. i it doesnt allow me enter 0 for first time. 0 is not allowed at pos, user can came to know only if he drag . that wat am trying to say

Comment: Use `drop` event and when is triggered, use timeout to execute a function which remove the invalid zeros.  Answer updated!

Comment: your previous answer is good. and its what am looking. i thing am confusing you in my explanation. i want it should behave like this http://jsfiddle.net/vM8U9/

Comment: Following your requirement, I've changed to `keydown`.  Now you can see the `0` and then it's removed.

Comment: @Idiot_cheg that's out of scope.  Now you need to complete :-)

Comment: @IvanSanz that's out of scope according to what was stated in the question.

Comment: "valid -123,238, 100,10336,101010,10001"

Comment: that's enough @Ele thanks for that code.. now working as expected . only need to avoid aplhas .. ll take care of that . thanks alot big bro

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that "0" is an invalid case?

If not, the simplest approach is:

```
function isValid(text) {
    return parseFloat(text).toString() === text;
}
```

Test:

```
var test = ["-123", "238", "100", "10336", "101010", "10001", "-001", "0", "01234234"];
var results = test.map(t => isValid(t));
```

Output:

```
[ true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false ]
```

Bonus: in case zero is an invalid case, just filter it out.

```
function isValid(text) {
    var numericValue = parseFloat(text).toString();
    return numericValue === text && numericValue !== "0";
}
```